# Data-Dependent Failure When Serializing std::vector to Boost Binary Archive

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

Just starting to familiarize myself with the Boost serialization library.  I'm stumped on what appears to be a data-dependent failure:

The following code fails with `input stream error`

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "boost/serialization/vector.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp"

int main (void) {

    std::vector<int> v1(100);
    std::generate(v1.begin(), v1.end(), &std::rand);

    {
        std::ofstream ofs("test.out");
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << v1;
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> v2;
        std::ifstream ifs("test.out");
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> v2;
        assert(v1 == v2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I use `boost::archive::text_[i/o]archive`, the code passes.

If I comment out the `std::generate` line (still using `binary_[i/o]archive`), the code passes.

On the surface, this is almost impossible to believe.  More likely, I am missing something obvious.

Lastly, using 1.53.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that your fstream is converting `0x0a` bytes that appear in your binary stream to your system line ending sequence which is not `0x0a`. Try opening your files with the `std::ios::binary` mode, e.g.

```
    std::ofstream ofs("test.out", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

and

```
    std::ifstream ifs("test.out", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: my bet is on this too